# Find monotonic function with definite integral = 1 for a given range

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find a function that has some specific characteristics, but I'm a bit stumped.

I'm trying to find a continuous function $f(x)$ that uses a given parameter $A$, where $A > 1$.  The following statements need to be true:

1. $f(0) = 0$
2. $f(A) = 1$
3. $f(x)$ is monotonic within the range $[0,A]$
4. $\int_0^Af(x)\,dx=1$ (i.e. the area under the curve from $0$ to $A$ is $1$)

Anyone have any ideas?  I keep coming up with functions that *almost* satisfy every one of those constraints, but haven't found one that satisfies them all.  I hope I'm not missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$ \int_0^A \alpha x^{\alpha-1} \, dx = A^{\alpha}-0, $$
for $\alpha>0$, we can take
$$ f(x) = \frac{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}}{A^{\alpha}} = \frac{\alpha}{x} \left( \frac{x}{A} \right)^{\alpha} $$
to make the integral $1$. Obviously $f(0)=0$. To get $f(1)=1$, take $\alpha=A$. Then
$$ f(x) = \left(\frac{x}{A}\right)^{A-1}. $$
For monotonicity, differentiate and notice that the derivative is nonnegative on $[0,A]$.

Comment: Aha!  I knew I was missing something.  I tried f(x) = (x/A)^A and it was close, but couldn't figure out where to go from there.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f(x)=(x/A)^p$ satisfies #1~3.

To make it satisfy #4, solve $\int_0^A (x/A)^p dx=1$, from which we have

> $p=A-1 \implies f(x)=(x/A)^{A-1}$